# Wicket JQuery AbstractFormDialog does not render RadioChoice of Enumeration

Tags: java, jquery-ui, wicket

I have a dialog box with a form. The form contains a radio choice consisting of some enum types. When the dialog opens, then only a single circle gets displayed. I expected three circles with the names of the enums. What's the error in my code?

```
public class MyNewDialog extends AbstractFormDialog {
  public MyNewDialog( String id ) {
    super( id, "Dialog title" );
    form = new Form( "dialogForm" );
    this.add( form );
    RadioChoice<Gender> genders = new RadioChoice<Gender>( "list",
    getGenderList(), new EnumChoiceRenderer<Gender>( this ) );
    genders.setSuffix( " - " );
    genders.setRequired( true );
    form.add( genders );
  }
private List<Gender> getGenderList() {
  return Arrays.asList<Gender>( Gender.values() );
}

//--- Enum class "Gender"
public enum Gender { MALE, FEMALE, FAMILY };

//--- The html markup in file "MyNewDialog.html"
<html xmlns:wicket="org.apache.wicket"><body><wicket:panel>
  <form wicket:id="dialogForm">
    <input wicket:id="list" type="radio" />
  </form>
</wicket:panel></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RadioChoice generates 'input' tags in the html.For this reason, you should not assign it in an input tag, but in a span or div.

Change your html markup file to:

```
//--- The html markup in file "MyNewDialog.html"
<html xmlns:wicket="org.apache.wicket"><body><wicket:panel>
  <form wicket:id="dialogForm">
    <span wicket:id="list" type="radio" />
  </form>
</wicket:panel></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See RadioChoice's javadoc: it renders one `<input>` tag for each option, thus it can not use an `<input>` tag by itself.

Your markup results in the following output:

```
<input>
  <input type="radio" />
  <input type="radio" />
  <input type="radio" />
</input>
```

Nothing problematic for Wicket, but surely not what your browser will accept.